# glob2 Package in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, package

I try to install glob2 package with this command in the terminal:
pip install glob2
But i received an error: 'pip: command not found' 
note: my platform is Python3 & Atom
would you please help me with it?

Comment: Have you tried `pip3`? Can be something with your environment variable PATH. Try `find / -name pip*` to locate.

Comment: oh yes with pip3, it woks correctly... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Extending on "Sianur's comment"

Sometimes we may get confused pip is part of which python version.

In that case below command will give details of pip Version.

```
$ pip -V
pip 18.1 from /home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

In this case, the pip is coming from python3.6 installation.

Hope this helps.